# Oria Gridx Server Side Pagination (dojo EnhancedGrid)

Tags: dojo, pagination, paging

As of dojo release 1.9, DataGrid and EnhancedGrid are formally deprecated.  Using sitepen's dgrid and oria gridx is recommended instead, respectively.

Has anyone used gridx to implement serverside / remote pagination?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer.  Setting the gridx's store with a 'dojo/store/JsonRest' store.

Then overriding the store's query function will give you access to the any plugin data (ie. Pagination and PaginationBar) and then passing any desired options to the server in the request.

Comment: you can answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45159531/stateful-server-side-filtering-in-dojo or here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45145547/filter-condition-not-retaing-in-enhanced-grid