# Stateful server side filtering in dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojox.grid

I am doing server side filtering in the enhanced grid in dojo 1.10 version. [Here](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojox/grid/EnhancedGrid/plugins/Filter.html#id6) in document it is clearly mentioned to use
isStateful property. Also, if we use isStateful property we need to use the URL parameter also, which according to 
documentation is

**When both isServerSide and isStateful are true, this is a place to set the server url, if it cannot be retrieved by store.url.**

I want to know how what is here **store.url**? I 
have searched in other sites, the other definition I get of url is from [here](https://svn.tbm.tudelft.nl/trac/TBM-CPS/RESEARCHTOOL/browser/Dev/trunk/src/client/dojox/grid/enhanced/plugins/Filter.js?rev=483) and [here](http://www.elementn.com/lib/dojo/util/docscripts/_browse2.php?ns=dojox&file=grid/enhanced/plugins/Filter.js&showall=)

**If using stateful, this is the url to send commands. default to store.url**

Can anybody provide a simple example or demo on how to use isStateful property. I am pretty much confused here. Do we need to have server side scripting for this?

Answer (score 1):

```
require(['dojo/store/JsonRest',
        'gridx/Grid',
        'gridx/core/model/cache/Async',
        'gridx/modules/SingleSort',
        'gridx/modules/pagination/Pagination',
        'gridx/modules/CellWidget',
        'dijit/registry',
        'gridx/modules/Bar',
        'gridx/support/LinkPager',
        'gridx/support/Summary',
        'dojo/domReady!'],function(Store, Grid, Async, Sort, Pagination, CellWidget, registry, Bar, LinkPager, Summary){
    var jsonStore = new Store({
        idProperty: "id", target: <your url>,
                 query: function(query, options) {  
                     var request = {};              
                     /* Paging Params. */
                     if (grid==null) {   
                         /* null on first call to server. */
                         request.currentPage=0;
                         request.pageSize=DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE;
                     } else {
                         request.currentPage=grid.pagination.currentPage();
                         request.pageSize=grid.pagination.pageSize();
                         if (request.pageSize==-1) {
                             /* Page size is -1 when 'ALL' records selected. Reset */
                              request.pageSize=DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE;
                        }
                     }
                     /* Sorting Parameters. */
                     if (options.sort == null) {
                         /* null on first render. */
                         request.sortAttribute="id";
                         request.descending=false;
                     } else {
                        request.sortAttribute=options.sort[0].attribute;
                        request.descending=options.sort[0].descending;
                     }
                     var results = Store.prototype.query.call(this, request);   
                     return results;
                 }  
             });
             grid = new Grid({
                 cacheClass: Async,
                 store: jsonStore,
                 structure: <your column definition>,
                 barBottom: [{pluginClass: Summary, style: 'text-align: left;'},{pluginClass: LinkPager, style: 'text-align: right;'}],
                 modules:[Sort, Pagination, Bar, CellWidget]}); 
             grid.pagination.setPageSize(DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE);
             registry.byId('gridDIV').set('content', grid);
             grid.startup();
         });
```

Comment: @shv22 you could try.  But depends which version of dojo you are using.  From 1.9 oria's Gridx is recommended.

Comment: I am using 1.10 dojo enhanced version...ok I will give it a try

Comment: no it didn't but I figured out the way to do it...we just need to give the url which will in return give us the reponse expected by grid and thats it rest it figured by enhanced grid itself...anyway voteup for your answer